# Adding cumulative totals at row level SSRS or SQL Server 2008r2

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to create a report in SSRS that would display data by YEAR.  Because I do not know the fixed years, I am creating this report using matrix (pivot) so years are dynamically created as a column.

What I need the report to look like:
I want the report to do a cumulative add per year at row level.

Assume:

1. GAAP Revenue for 2017 for Lease Assumption Key '20300' = $100.
2. GAAP Revenue for 2018 for Lease Assumption Key '20300' = $120.
3. GAAP Revenue for 2019 for Lease Assumption Key '20300' = $150.

Based on Assumption:

1. I want 2017 GAAP Revenue for Lease Assumption Key 20300 to display = $100.
2. I want 2018 GAAP Revenue for Lease Assumption Key 20300 to display = $220.
3. I want 2018 GAAP Revenue for Lease Assumption Key 20300 to display = $370.

Similar should happen to "Cash Revenue" rows.

Is this possible in SSRS?  If not, how would I go about doing this in SQL Server 2008r2?

Here's what I've done so far in SSRS:

Matrix Design:
[image]

Matrix Result:
[image]

Comment: You should be able to use the `RunningValue` function. Try this `=RunningValue(Fields!GAAPRevenue.Value, SUM,"datasetname")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `RunningValue` function. Try this

```
=RunningValue(Fields!GAAPRevenue.Value, SUM,"datasetname")
```